# Вопрос про array_map. Как изменить возвращаемый массив?

Tags: php

У меня есть исходный массив. Его я получаю при помощи **array_map**

```
$return_array_map = [
    0 => [
        235 => [
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2',
        ],
    ],
    1 => [
        659 => [
            'key3' => 'value3',
            'key4' => 'value4',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Но мне требуется получить такой массив:

```
$result = [
    235 => [
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
    ],
    659 => [
        'key3' => 'value3',
        'key4' => 'value4',
    ],
];
```

Могу ли я при помощи **array_map** сразу получить массив **$result**?

Comment: Вместо array_map  возможно тогда использовать array_reduce

Comment: Если бы мы видели код который генерирует такой массив, то мы бы подсказали.

Comment: php.net: `array_map - Применяет callback-функцию ко всем элементам указанных массивов`. То есть Ваш массив получен некоей функцией примененной к исходному массиву. Как написал выше @u_mulder без кода этой функции мы не сможем Вам помочь и показать в ней место, где Ваш исходный массив лишний раз засовывается в еще один массив.

Comment: Не суть как работает там функция. Это же не взаимосвязано. Функция возвращает массив с ключом 'key1' и значением [...]. Какая бы обработка не была, всё это записывается в новый массив. Вопрос, как скомпоновать возврат функции, что бы получился массив $result